# Removing union from mysql query to get 2 row output in a single row

Tags: mysql, sql, database

Here is mysql query

```
SELECT CallDate,SUM(Hour0) AS FailedCalls FROM call_status WHERE CallDate='2012-09-14' AND CallStatusId NOT IN (42,52)

UNION

SELECT CallDate,SUM(Hour0) AS SuccessCalls FROM call_status WHERE CallDate='2012-09-14' AND CallStatusId IN (42,52);
```

Here is the output
[image]

Sorry for the small image.
As you can see i have selected Failed Calls from above query and SuccessCalls using second query.But what i want is CallDate,FailedCalls,SuccessCalls in a single row.

***Update:***
Here is the correct query:

```
SELECT CallDate,
SUM(CASE WHEN (CallStatusId NOT IN(42,52)) THEN Hour0
ELSE 0 
END) AS FailedCalls,
SUM(CASE WHEN (CallStatusId IN (42,52)) THEN Hour0
ELSE 0
END) AS SuccessCalls
FROM call_status
WHERE CallDate='2012-09-14';
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something along these lines?

```
SELECT CallDate
      ,SUM( CASE WHEN (Hour0 != 42 AND Hour0 != 52) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END ) AS FailedCalls
      ,SUM( CASE WHEN (Hour0  = 42  OR Hour0  = 52) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END ) AS SuccessCalls
  FROM call_status
  WHERE CallDate='2012-09-14'
```

Comment: thnks going by ur lines solved my problem :) I have updated my correct query.